# Looking for a simpler way of calculating average

Tags: pine-script

Is there a simpler/cleaner way of calculating this in Pine Script

```
  avgfiveK=avg(fiveK,fiveK[1],fiveK[2],fiveK[3],fiveK[4],fiveK[5],fiveK[6],fiveK[7],fiveK[8],fiveK[9])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [simple moving average](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dsma) for that.
*The sma function returns the moving average, that is the sum of last y values of x, divided by y.*

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

avgfiveK = ta.sma(fiveK, 10)

plot(avgfiveK)
```